# C# Winforms Visual Studio designer cannot find custom type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a custom control with a generic list of custom types. This list is defined public:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), Editor(typeof(ButtonPanelXEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public List<CompactButton> CompactButtons
{
    get { return _compactButtons; }
    set { _compactButtons = value; }
}
```

When I add this control to my form and build my project I get this error:

> Error 1 Could not find a type for a name.  The type name was 'ButtonPanelX.CompactButton, ButtonPanelX, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Line 127, position 5. D:\Projecten\ButtonPanelX\ButtonPanelX\Form1.resx 127 5 ButtonPanelX

When I use strings instead of custom objects, the desginer does save my list. `CompactButton` has the attribute `[Serializable]` and derives from `ISerializable`

What can I do to fix this?

Edit:

```
public class ButtonPanelXEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        if (context != null && context.Instance != null)
            // We will use a window for property editing. 
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;

        return base.GetEditStyle(context);
    }

    public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {

        context.OnComponentChanging();

        ButtonPanel b = context.Instance as ButtonPanel;

        FooBar form = new FooBar();
        form.Buttons = b.CompactButtons;

        form.ShowDialog();

        b.CompactButtons = form.Buttons;

        b.DrawButtons();

        context.OnComponentChanged();

        return form.Buttons;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class ButtonPanel : UserControl
{
    private ArrayList _compactButtons;

    public ButtonPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _compactButtons = new ArrayList();

        AddButtons();

        this.Load += new EventHandler(ButtonPanel_Load);

    }

    void ButtonPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawButtons();
    }


    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), Editor(typeof(ButtonPanelXEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public ArrayList CompactButtons
    {
        get { return _compactButtons; }
    }

    public void DrawButtons()
    {
        baseButton1.Visible = ((CompactButton)_compactButtons[0]).Visible;
        baseButton2.Visible = ((CompactButton)_compactButtons[1]).Visible;
    }

    private void AddButtons()
    {
        /* Buttons baseButton1 and baseButton2 are created by the designer */

        CompactButton c = new CompactButton();
        c.Enabled = baseButton1.Enabled;
        c.Visible = baseButton1.Visible;
        c.Name = baseButton1.Name;

        CompactButton c2 = new CompactButton();
        c2.Enabled = baseButton2.Enabled;
        c2.Visible = baseButton2.Visible;
        c2.Name = baseButton2.Name;

        _compactButtons.Add(c);
        _compactButtons.Add(c2);
    }
}
```

Comment: is your type named *CompactButton* or *CompactButtons*? In your code snippet you refer to it as CompactButton while in your question-text you say CompactButtons.

Comment: My type is named `CompactButton`. Ive edited my question.

Comment: What is the target framework version for your project? Google says there are some problems if the target is the 3.5 framework.

Comment: I've found that too, but changing it to version 4 doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Why are you serializing your buttons to the resource file and not to the code behind?

Comment: I don't know exacty what you mean, but I want to set some properties of the buttons at design time. So, the settings set on design time must be remembered when starting the application. Is there another way to do this? (I'm using winforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of serializing your buttons to the resource file, you could try to serialize them to the code behind. For this you need to implement a custom `TypeDescriptor` for your `CompactButton` type and there handle convertion to an `InstanceDescriptor`. Look at [How to Implement a TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx). Example:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(CompactButtonTypeConverter))]
public class CompactButton: ... {
  ...
}

public class CompactButtonTypeConverter: TypeConverter {

  public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {
    if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)) 
       return true;
    return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
  }

  public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
    if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor) && value is CompactButton) {
      // This assumes you have a public default constructor on your type.
      ConstructorInfo ctor = typeof(CompactButton).GetConstructor();
      if (ctor != null) 
         return new InstanceDescriptor(ctor, new object[0], false);
    }
    return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);      
  }

}
```

For more information also see the [InstanceDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.instancedescriptor.aspx) class.

**UPDATE**: As for your `UITypeEditor` and the CompactButtons property, you do not need a setter. Change your CompactButtons property as follows:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), Editor(typeof(ButtonPanelXEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public List<CompactButton> CompactButtons
{
    get { return _compactButtons; } // _compactButtons must of course be initialized.
}
```

Then you could implement the EditValue method of `UITypeEditor` like so:

```
public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context,
  IServiceProvider provider, object value) {
  if (context == null || provider == null)
    return null;

  var b = context.Instance as ButtonPanel;
  if (b == null)
    return value;

  var editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)
    provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
  if (editorService == null)
    return null;

  // This constructor should copy the buttons in its own list.
  using (var form = new FooBar(b.CompactButtons)) {
    if (editorService.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK && context.OnComponentChanging()) {
      b.CompactButtons.Clear();
      b.CompactButtons.AddRange(form.Buttons);
      context.OnComponentChanged();
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```

If your editor form is not very specialized you could maybe try out the [CollectionEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor.aspx).

Comment: What do you mean by serializing to the code behind? How can I do this? Can you post a little sample code?

Comment: Thank you for providing an example. But I still don't understand how I can use this. Where does the serialization takes place? Where do I need to do that? How can I open the code behind? I'm sorry, but it sounds like Chinese for me. (and I'm from Holland :))

Comment: Code behind for winforms is in the .Designer file, in your case you should have a Form1.Designer.cs. Therein is a partial class definition, which contains the InitializeComponent method and everything you change on the forms designer is serialized as code to that method or to the resource file if type being serialized does not support CodeDom serialization.

Comment: Okay, and in my case, visual studio stores the values in the resx file. Your suggestion is not to do this, right? You suggest to do this in the partial designer class. But I still don't understand how I can do this. Somewhere in my code I have to open the designer.cs and insert some C# code? How?

Comment: Code in the InitializeComponent method is generated via CodeDom serialization. To provide capability for CodeDom serialization, your type must either be associated with a `TypeConverter` which supports conversion to an `InstanceDescriptor` object or provide a custom `CodeDomSerializer`. In most cases a `TypeConverter` is enough. If you implement a `TypeConverter` for your `CompactButton` as in my example, that should be enough. Winforms designer will then be able to convert your `CompactButton` to an `InstanceDescriptor` which can then be serialized to the InitializeComponent.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I learn a lot today :) However, when I set some properties of a `CompactButton` in design time and I build the project for the first time, I get the expected results. Everything works fine. But then.. when I edit some properties on the same `CompactButton`, the designer.cs is *not* updated. So, in short, after a build, the designer.cs does not update the properties for the `CompactButton`

Comment: In your `UITypeEditor` in EditValue method, try calling the `ITypeDescriptorContext` methods OnComponentChanging before you change a value and OnComponentChanged after you change it.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't do the trick. In my startpost I have posted my UITypeEditor class

Comment: I have implemented your sample code. The designer.cs is updated correctly, but when I run the application it does nothing do with the properties set in the designer! For completeness, I've edited my startpost with the custom panel class.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Based on your code I would guess you are trying to set the visibility of baseButton1 and baseButton2 which you added to the panel through the designer? If my guess is correct and you always have just those two buttons then the easiest way is to make them public. Or you could create properties on your panel which would then manipulate the buttons, like Button1Visible, Button1Enabled etc.

Comment: This is just a test project. Eventually it must be possible to add custom buttons to the custom panel. The custom panel always has some default buttons, which properties can be set by the designer. But it must also be possible to add custom buttons and set their properties, also in design time

Comment: If default buttons should be removable then you probably only need to add them in design time. You can add them in getter for CompactButtons if DesignMode property is `true`. If they should not be removable then expose them through a different property or properties. Collection serialization is a bit limited, you can only add to it, but not modify any objects that are already in the collection (your default buttons, for example).

Comment: Okay, thanks. But there are more properties which can be set for a button: enabled, image and tooltiptext. That is why I have created a custom class (CompactButton) which contains these properties. At the moment the buttons must displayed on the control, I create a button and set the properties based on the `CompactButton` object. Finally I have the properties correctly set in the designer, but now in runtime these properties aren't set! :(

Comment: I've been playing with only add buttons to the panel which must be visible. So, in my ButtonPanel I have a list with buttons which must be visible. But when I remove a button from that list, the button stays in the designer.cs instead of removing the button.

Comment: No, as per the code in your question, properties will not be set in runtime. Why? In design time you create two new `CompactButton` objects, which are also serialized to the code behind. In runtime two NEW buttons are created in the constructor and after that buttons from design time are added, so you should have four `CompactButton` objects in runtime. But the first two buttons are always those that are added from constructor and always have default properties. That is why it appears the properties are not being set in runtime.

Comment: If buttons stay serialized in code behind most probable causes are either you are not correctly removing them from the collection or are not calling the OnComponentChanging/Changed methods. I strongly suggest that you take some time and read about CodeDom serialization, type descriptors and winforms design-time support.

Comment: Thank you. I will dive into the material. Do you know sites where this material is explained? And where it has something to do with my situation?

Comment: This MSDN page can be your starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37899azc.aspx. There were also plenty of examples on Code Project, though that was a few years ago. I guess they should still be there :)

Comment: Thnx. I have read a lot about it now. However, sometime I get errors and when I restart VS I don't have the error anymore. The error occurs when I drag my custom buttonpanel to a form. The error is: `Code generataion for property 'CompactButtons' failed Error was: 'List<CompactButton> is unable to convert List[CompactButton] ... to InstanceDescriptor'` I've tried to create a custom Collection with a TypeConverter. But I still have the same error.

Comment: And I can't find a solution for the problem that the designer values or not set in runtime. They suggest, like you did, to use the OnComponentChanging/Changed methods. But I do call this methods with no result.

Comment: Have you found the solution? If not then I can try and implement a sample, if that will be of help.